# Doctrine2 One-To-Many, Unidirectional with Join Table with data in Join Table

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm working with Symfony2 and I have this schema:

```
Products:
  id
  name
  value

List:
  id
  owner_name
  created_at
  status
```

I read how to make [relations with Join Table in Doctrine2 docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-unidirectional-with-join-table) and all works fine. But now, I want to add one field (status) to the table products_list to have:

```
products_list:
  product_id
  list_id
  status
```

Any help?

thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the association should stay a oneToMany, you have to make a thrid entity.

```
products_list
  product(OneToOne)
  list(ManyToOne)
  status

list:
  products_list(OneToMany)

products:
  products_list(OneToOne)
```